# CraftingManager error

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm a newbie in Minecraft and I need help. Whats the problem? I think this is related with CraftingManager. When I start the game, loading comes to initialization and minecraft crashes. Please help!
Minecraft version: 1.7.10, Forge version: 10.13.4.1558, Eclipse version: Oxygen.

crash:

```
at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.item.crafting.CraftingManager.addRecipe(CraftingManager.java:232)
at cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry.addShapedRecipe(GameRegistry.java:250)
at cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry.addRecipe(GameRegistry.java:245)
at org.flakerZ.LotsOfThings.LotsOfThings.init(LotsOfThings.java:84)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at cpw.mods.fml.common.FMLModContainer.handleModStateEvent(FMLModContainer.java:532)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74)
at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275)
at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.sendEventToModContainer(LoadController.java:212)
at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.propogateStateMessage(LoadController.java:190)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74)
at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275)
at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.distributeStateMessage(LoadController.java:119)
at cpw.mods.fml.common.Loader.initializeMods(Loader.java:737)
at cpw.mods.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.finishMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:311)
at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.startGame(Minecraft.java:597)
```

code (main class, initalization):

```
@EventHandler
    public void init(FMLInitializationEvent event) {
        GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(itemPerfectCheese, 1), new Object[]{ "MM", "CC", "BB",('M'), itemMeltedCheese, ('B'), Items.bowl, ('C'), itemCheese});

        GameRegistry.addShapelessRecipe(new ItemStack(itemReinforcedCheese, 1), new Object[] {itemCheese, itemMeltedCheese, itemPerfectCheese});

        GameRegistry.addSmelting(Items.milk_bucket, new ItemStack(itemCheese,1), 5.0F);
        GameRegistry.addSmelting(itemCheese, new ItemStack(itemMeltedCheese, 1), 10.0F);

        GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(itemCheesePickaxe, 1), new Object[]{ "CCC", " S ", " S ",('C'), itemReinforcedCheese, ('S'), Items.stick});
        GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(itemCheeseAxe, 1), new Object[]{ "CC", "CS", " S ",('C'), itemReinforcedCheese, ('S'), Items.stick});
        GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(itemCheeseShovel, 1), new Object[]{ "C", "S", "S",('C'), itemReinforcedCheese, ('S'), Items.stick});
        GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(itemCheeseHoe, 1), new Object[]{ "CC", " S", " S",('C'), itemReinforcedCheese, ('S'), Items.stick});
        GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(itemCheeseSword, 1), new Object[]{ "C", "C", "S",('C'), itemReinforcedCheese, ('S'), Items.stick});

    }

}
```

crash

```
org.flakerZ.LotsOfThings.LotsOfThings.init(LotsOfThings.java‌​:84) ~[bin/:?]
```

Comment: Can you post your full stacktrace?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Z82T7gGt

Comment: Just wondering, but which is your mod? `examplemod`, or `lotsofthings`?

Comment: @Edric lots of things, examplemod is only example, I didn't edit it, it already was.

Answer (score 2):

A few other things, not exactly causing your current problem, but which are unneeded, causing another problem, or could otherwise cleaner or more flexible.

1. You don't need `new Object[]{}`, that's [what varargs does](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).  The reason vanilla code has `new Object[]{}` is because the compiler compiles `varargs...` into a boxed object array and the decompile process can't tell them apart. It's called [Syntactic Sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar).
2. This recipe will fail

   ```
   GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(itemCheeseAxe, 1), new Object[]{ "CC", "CS", " S ",('C'), itemReinforcedCheese, ('S'), Items.stick});
   ```

   Why? Because `"CC", "CS", " S "` aren't all the same length: 2, 2, and 3. The recipe is not square and will cause an error when the game is run.
3. `('C')`,`('S')` etc. Excess parens, you don't need them. But they're not hurting anything.
4. You might want to use `ShapedOreRecipes` and replace `Items.Stick` with `"stickWood"` so that mod-added sticks will function for your recipes.

Answer (score 1):

You are not adding an item properly ! http://www.wuppy29.com/minecraft/1-8-tutorial/forge-modding-tutorials-1-8-crafting-recipes/#sthash.8j4SP17W.dpbs use this article. This should work

In your case :

```
 GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(itemPerfectCheese, 1),  "MM", "CC", "BB","M", itemMeltedCheese, "B", Items.bowl, "C", itemCheese});
```

(Following the site metioned above)

Comment: Yes, I change my code, even did the mod on the other Minecraft Forge versions.

Comment: What did you change? And did it work on the other MF versions?

Comment: Already not working on other Forge versions. Let's solve this problem? And dismantle this crash?

Comment: What do you mean? If you about a separate class for CraftingManager, then no. I write all crafts in init (you can see where)

Comment: edited my question; hope it helps! ;) And mark it solved if it does.

Comment: No problem! Just mark your question as solved / mark the answer as correct